# Counting items in droppable area in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I have an accordion and loop of droppable areas. I manage to count items for both droppable fields, but i got the problem with counting, I need it to count each row separate, not both rows together. I have a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/montel388/n5df9upr/) here, its working fine for one row, but when im trying to make it loop problem appears.
And also how can i decrement item after item is removed?

Here is code with loop:

```
<body style="background-color:white;" onload="startTime()"> 
<h1 class="ui-widget-header">Products</h1>    
<div id="myAccordion">
<h3><a href="#">T-Shirts</a></h3>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>Lolcat Shirt</li>
            <li>Cheezeburger Shirt</li>
            <li>Buckit Shirt</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
<h3><a href="#">Bags</a></h3>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>Zebra Striped</li>
            <li>Black Leather</li>
            <li>Alligator Leather</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
<h3><a href="#">Gadgets</a></h3>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>iPhone</li>
            <li>iPod</li>
            <li>iPad</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<label>
<?php
    $len=2;
    for($y=0;$y<$len;$y++)
    {
        echo "<div class='proc'> <pre>";
        echo "<span> </span><br /></pre>";  
?>
    <div id="procLeader">
        <label>Box1:</label>
        <div class="ui-widget-content">
        <div id="procleader">
            <ol>
                <li class="placeholder" name="procleader">Add here</li>
                <input type="hidden" name="procleader" id="hiddenListInput3" />
            </ol>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="procChecker">
        <label>Box2:</label>
        <div class="ui-widget-content">
        <div id="procchecker">
            <ol>
                <li class="placeholder" name="procchecker">Add here</li>
                <input type="hidden" name="procchecker" id="hiddenListInput4" />
            </ol>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php       
    echo "</div>";                      
    }
?>
</label>
</body>
```

Comment: `each row separate` OR `each box separate`? Can you please explain where is row in output?

Comment: @vijayP each row separate, but for both boxes together

Comment: oh ok..so you mean to say Box1 - Box2 combination will repeat and we may have this pair multiple time on page. And we want to show `Items Dropped: (some number).` text for each pair. Please confirm

Comment: @vijayP yes correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this code. The main idea is to have unique `id` within HTML dialog. So if we are creating DOM in loop then don't try to assign them `id`; instead go for `class`. Here I have added 2 rows and changed `id` to `class` within HTML, JS and CSS too:

https://jsfiddle.net/n5df9upr/16/

```
$(function() {
          var itm = [];
          $("#savebutton").click(function() {
            LISTOBJ.saveList();
          });
          $("#myAccordion").accordion({
            heightStyle: "content",
            active: false,
            collapsible: true
          });
          $("#myAccordion li").draggable({
            appendTo: "body",
            helper: "clone"
          });
          $(".leader ol").droppable({
            activeClass: "ui-state-default",
            hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
            accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",
            drop: function(event, ui) {
              var zz = ui.draggable.text()
              var xyz = itm.includes(zz);
              if (xyz === false) {
                $(this).find(".placeholder").remove();
                $("<li></li>").text(ui.draggable.text())
                  //.addClass("cart-item")
                  .addClass('dropClass')
                  .appendTo(this);

                //add to array
                itm.push(zz);
                //add style
                $('.ui-droppable').find("li.ui-draggable:contains('" + zz + "')").addClass('bred');
                var n = $(this).closest("div.proc").find(".dropClass").length; //finding the items within own container
                $(this).closest("div.proc").find("span").text("Items Dropped: " + n + "."); //setting the text in own container

              } else {
                alert('Name is Already Exist');
              }

            }
          }).sortable({
            items: "li:not(.placeholder)",
            sort: function() {
              $(this).removeClass("ui-state-default");
            }
          });
          $(".checker ol").droppable({
            activeClass: "ui-state-default",
            hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
            accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",
            drop: function(event, ui) {
              var zz = ui.draggable.text()
              var xyz = itm.includes(zz);
              if (xyz === false) {
                $(this).find(".placeholder").remove();
                $("<li></li>").text(ui.draggable.text())
                  //.addClass("cart-item")
                  .addClass('dropClass')
                  .appendTo(this);

                //add to array
                itm.push(zz);
                //add style
                $('.ui-droppable').find("li.ui-draggable:contains('" + zz + "')").addClass('bred');
                var n = $(this).closest("div.proc").find(".dropClass").length;
                $(this).closest("div.proc").find("span").text("Items Dropped: " + n + ".");

              } else {
                alert('Name is Already Exist');
              }

            }
          }).sortable({
            items: "li:not(.placeholder)",
            sort: function() {
              $(this).removeClass("ui-state-default");
            }
          });
          $("#myAccordion ul").droppable({
            drop: function(event, ui) {
              $(ui.draggable).remove();
              var zz = ui.draggable.text()
              $('.ui-droppable').find("li.ui-draggable:contains('" + zz + "')").removeClass('bred');

              var indexItm = itm.indexOf(zz);
              if (indexItm > -1) {
                itm.splice(indexItm, 1);
              }
            },
            hoverClass: "ui-state-hover"
              //accept: '.cart-item'
          });
        });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, so is it better to use class when dealing with loops?

Comment: @YevgeniyBagackiy - yes, absolutely. Go for `class` and use jQuery's `$.closest` and `$.find` to work within your each block/row.

Comment: Thanks a lot for help. What about decreasing number of dropped items after it removed. How i can do this?